# How can i create col span or row span on dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void CreateRuntime_Table()
    {
        int tblRows = int.Parse(txtrow.Text);
        int tblCols = int.Parse(txtcol.Text);

        Table tbl = new Table();
        tbl.BorderWidth = 3;
        tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        tbl.ID = "myTable";

        for (int i = 1; i <= tblRows; i++)
        {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 1; j <= tblCols; j++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
                txtbox.Text = "Test Row:" + i + "Test Col:" + " " + j;
                //Add the control to the table cell
                tc.Controls.Add(txtbox);
                tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            }

            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

        form1.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateRuntime_Table();
    }
```

I have created a dynamic table using c#. How do I set a colspan on the dynamic table using a textbox?

For example if I place a value 3 in the text box and click on Apply Span button  then the colspan of a dynamic table should change accordingly.

Check the Image below.

I am new to c#, pls help

Thanks.

[UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVjU2.png)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: You have not mentioned -how- you create this dynamic table. This matters, because that is the code where the colspan should be set. Please add a relevant code-snippet to your question.

Comment: Class `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell` has properties `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan`. You should assign to them.

Comment: will you please elaborate with code. @MichalŠuvada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML col-span and row-span attributes are represented by `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` properties of `TableCell` class.

In your code, you should add assigning of those properties to `TableCell tc`.

```
public void CreateRuntime_Table()
{
    int tblRows = int.Parse(txtrow.Text);
    int tblCols = int.Parse(txtcol.Text);
    //I would recommend using int.TryParse with some defaults
    int colSpan = 0;
    int rowSpan = 0;
    int.TryParse(tbColspanName.Text, out colSpan);
    int.TryParse(tbRowspanName.Text, out rowSpan);

    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.BorderWidth = 3;
    tbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    tbl.ID = "myTable";

    for (int i = 1; i <= tblRows; i++)
    {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 1; j <= tblCols; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell()
            {
                //assign entered col / row span
                ColumnSpan = colSpan,
                RowSpan = rowSpan
            };
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            txtbox.Text = "Test Row:" + i + "Test Col:" + " " + j;
            //Add the control to the table cell
            tc.Controls.Add(txtbox);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    form1.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal Suvada for replay, when i try this its just showing the same table.     The ColumnSpan and RowSpan Not Woking as Expected.

Comment: @SaifAK, then you should check if the spacing isn't caused by `TextBox` `padding` or `margin` css properties. Easiest way is by inspecting the elements in browser.